# CPanel New Domain

Tags: apache-httpd, cpanel

Background Note: When I first asked this here, I was told that it is off topic and I should ask at StackOverflow. StackOverflow said it is off topic and I should ask on ServerFault. Serverfault said it is off topic and I should ask on Unix&Linux. So, I am asking again here.

I am trying to add a new domain using CPanel. I went into Addon Domains and added the domain. I went into the domain's folder and added an index.html file. When I go to http://sottovoci.net, I get

```
Template Error: The template file must be given (or the template could not be opened)
```

I've been Googling for a week and I haven't found a solution to this problem. However, I have found that if I go to http://sottovoci.net/index.html, I get the placeholder index page that I made. Further, if I go to http://www.sottovoci.net, it defaults to the index page. If I go to http://sottovoci.net, it default to http://sottovoci.net/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi instead of using index.html.

Now, having spent the weekend reading endless documentation that all says to just add the domain and it magically works, I am out of sources of information to search. Where does CPanel hide whatever setting it is that is redirecting to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi instead of index.html? How can I change it to use index.html instead of cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi?

Comment: It sounds like you have a redirect or rewrite enabled somewhere... Has there already been troubleshooting done on all those other questions? If so, could you provide links, at least to the one here (I couldn't find it on your profile, but maybe that's because its closed).

Comment: I received no troubleshooting advice. I have been hunting for the string "defaultwebpage.cgi" on the entire harddrive. I found it in the MySQL install. So, I think cPanel has it as a setting in MySQL somewhere. Trying to figure out the MySQL user/pass now so I can hunt through the data in there.

Comment: Haven't actually personally used cPanel in a long time, but the docs say https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Redirects ... of course, you probably already know that. If you can't figure out the MySQL password, recovering it is fairly easy... not sure if we (or [dba.se], or [sf], or [so]) already have a question on that or not.

Comment: @derobert Thanks. I've never used cPanel before. It is hell. I checked redirects. There are none (it actually says, "you have no redirects"). It is to me as though the directoryindex setting in Apache is set to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi for "sottovoci.net", but properly set to index.html for "www.sottovoci.net". The problem is that cPanel doesn't use the /etc/httpd/httpd.conf file (or anything in that directory). It uses some other settings, so I am having a hell of a time trying to fix it.

Comment: I am leaving this here because I've seen so many people ask about this. The solution turned out to be in my web browser. Google Chrome and Firefox both cached the fact that http://sottovoci.net redirects to http://sottovoci.net/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi and refused to behave otherwise. I cleared the history on both browsers and now they properly redirect to http://sottovoci.net/index.html

Comment: Please post that as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

There are many causes for this error:

```
Template Error: The template file must be given (or the template could not be opened)
```

In this case, the problem was caused by this process:

1. Added sottovoci.net to cPanel using the "Addon Domains" interface from the main cPanel interface.
2. cPanel created the directory/folder for sottovoci.net with nothing in it.
3. I went to sottovoci.net and I was redirected to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi. I don't have any cgi templates set up, so I got the error that there was no defaultwebpage.cgi template.
4. I created the index.html file.
5. I went to sottovoci.net and I was immediately redirected to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi again. I did not see the the index.html page I created.

What happened is a hidden step right after step 3. My web browser stored in a cache that sottovoci.net redirects to sottovoci.net/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi. So, even though I created the index.html file, my web browser refused to check to see if it was there. It immediately forced a redirect.

The solution, in this case, was to flush my browser's history (every browser has some setting, usually in privacy or security, to flush browser history). Once flushed, my web browser actually asked the server what to do and the server redirected to sottovoci.net/index.html.